# Mixing C pre/post increment/decrement with Objective-C dot operator works?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Say I have a class with a scalar property type:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int myInt;
```

And for clarity, synthesized like:

```
@synthesize myInt = _myInt;
```

If someone had asked me if the following line would work:

```
self.myInt++;
```

I would have said "No". The rationale being that we all know that the dot operator is just syntactic sugar for calling a compiler-generated getter method. So that line is literally:

```
[self myInt]++;
```

If you type that second line into Xcode, it won't compile, stating: "Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an objective-c message not allowed". This makes perfect sense, and it's what I would have expected. Even if that compiled, I would have expected the outcome to increment a copy of the backing ivar on the stack, not the ivar itself.

But, the instruction `self.myInt++` does compile, and it works. It works just as if that dot operator were directly accessing _myInt. By supplying my own getters and setters, I can see that both the getter and the setter are used in the process, in that order, like it was actually:

```
[self setMyInt:[self myInt] + 1];
```

So, is this an exception to the rule that the dot operator is exactly the same as a method call, or are the `{--, ++, +=, -=}` operators given special attention by the Objective-C compiler when used with dot notation? I've always thought of them as a C language features with no special considerations for Objective-C. I could see that simple line being very confusing to someone unfamiliar with Objective-C dot notation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can look at the assembler output and see that it generates two `_objc_msgSend` calls.

I'd guess it's more a case of applying the rule that `a++` is syntactic sugar for `a = a + 1`

Comment: Do prefix operators (`++self.myInt`) also apply?

Comment: Looking at the disassembler output, I see two `objc_msgSend` so yes. You are incrementing the property.