# Objective-C can I short hand += increment properties?

Tags: objective-c, ios, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mixing C pre/post increment/decrement with Objective-C dot operator works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936067/mixing-c-pre-post-increment-decrement-with-objective-c-dot-operator-works)

I'm debugging a piece of code that I wrote. Within it, I'm using a shorthand to increment a property of a class

```
 objectiveCClass.declaredProperty+= 1;
```

is this kind of increment legal?

Comment: Why not just test it yourself with `objectiveCClass.declaredProperty = objectiveCClass.declaredProperty + 1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works

This code:

```
MyObj *m = [[MyObj alloc] init];
m.foo += 1;
NSLog(@"%d", m.foo);

m.foo += 2;
NSLog(@"%d", m.foo);
```

Outputs:
1
3

foo is a synthesized int property:

```
@property (assign) int foo;
```

I believe it will do

```
[m setFoo:([m foo] +1)];
```

Comment: You're kidding me, I never thought that would work.

Comment: I wasn't sure either until I tried it :o  I expected what you thought.  objc seems like a message passing system.  Seems counter intuitive in that model.  But to me, so does the dot syntax ;)

Comment: @bryanmac I suspect that it was included for ease-of-use purposes because obj-C is a superset of C,

Answer (score 8):

```
self.declaredProperty += 1;
```

is shorthand for

```
[self setDeclaredProperty:self.declaredProperty + 1];
```